# Scala Play 2.3 Getting request back in scope

Tags: scala, playframework, request, implicit

Sorry for my lack of correct terminology, but hopefully the questions is at least understandable :)

I'm implementing a trait which is called out to by a library - so I don't have access over the "middle" of the code.

Controller -> Action (get request in scope) -> Library -> Trait -> my code to save to database

**Trying**

```
def insert(newRecord: Token)(implicit request: play.api.mvc.Request[Any]) = database.withSession { implicit db:Session => {
```

**Gives** a compile error:
    *Cannot find any HTTP Request here*

Is there anyway to get the request back in scope?

**The code:**
Specifically, I'm using play2-oauth2-provider, and the relevant pieces of code as I understand are

Get request in scope in Action, this is working correctly

```
def accessToken = Action.async {
    implicit request =>
      val header = request.remoteAddress
      issueAccessToken(new UserOauth())
```

The request then gets passed through the library (a few times) - the last point in the library code which request is still in scope is a call -

```
handler.handleRequest(request, dataHandler)

  override def handleRequest[U](request: AuthorizationRequest, dataHandler: DataHandler[U]): GrantHandlerResult = {
    .....
    issueAccessToken(dataHandler, authInfo)
  }
```

The last line of handleRequest calls to issueAccessToken.

**By my understanding, this is where the reference to request is lost, and my question is - "is there any way to get it back."** Again, I can't change this code as its in a library.

```
  def issueAccessToken[U](dataHandler: DataHandler[U], authInfo: AuthInfo[U]): GrantHandlerResult = {
    ...
 dataHandler.createAccessToken(authInfo)
    }
```

My code is then

```
class UserOauth extends DataHandler[Credentials] {

  def createAccessToken....
```

Which eventually calls my data model - where I would like to get something from the request object

Thanks,
Brent

Comment: Your issue is quite unclear. In `def insert(newRecord: Token)(implicit request: play.api.mvc.Request[Any]) = database.withSession { implicit db:Session => yourCode }`, yourCode has access `request` (thanks to closure). `Action` functions `apply` and `async` both provides `request`.

Comment: The issue is that the def insert code results in a compile error. I formatted my question so hopefully that is more apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `insert` function is requiring a request from the context/caller (that's what the `implicit request` means there). Not finding a request provided as implicit, the compiler raise the error.

To fix it, you have to declare an implicit for current request (provided by Play Action) in the code calling `insert`. `implicit` must be corresponding side by side, between caller and callee, e.g.

```scala
def myAction = Action { implicit req => // instead of just Action { req => ... }
  insert(myRec)
}

def myAsyncAction = Action async { implicit req =>
  Future { insert(myRec)
}
```

Any `implicit parameter` is looking for a matching `implicit value` (`def` or `val`) in current `implicit scope` (from the caller).

Making everying 'explicit' can help to understand `insert` (and is also sometime better as code), as an `implicit parameter` is by first a parameter, so following code is also right.

```scala
def myAction = Action { req => insert(myRecord)(req) }
```

Comment: I do have an implicit at the controller, and this is working. My problem is the request is not being passed "all the way" to my db layer - and the call chain is coming through a 3rd party library

Comment: You need to make your code clearer so that issue can be understandable. If you try code in answer, you will see `implicit` resolution is working.

Comment: Yes, I agree the implicit resolution within the Action does work.
As I'm using a library, part of the problem is some of the code is not in my control.
If you can point out which parts of my question are unclear then perhaps I can improve the question?

Comment: As implicit resolution is working. You have to make clear at which step the implicit is not passed, at which call, and pasting the code at caller side, and the def of the callee (called function).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the question with (hopefully) better code extracts - is it possible to understand now?

Comment: Nope. You've paste the whole code, without focus on the exact place where you get an issue. The question is still too large/fuzzy. Better would be to have something like: "here is my function `def f ... // declaration without body if not required` here is how I call it `f(...)`, why implicit is not passed?". For now, it's like having to understand a big bunch of code before guessing where you think there is an issue.

Comment: revised to focus the code to my understanding of where the issue is occuring

Comment: You really need to write question in way people not known your project can understand it. Request can't be lost when calling `issueAccessToken` as this function as no `request` argument (`implicit` or not). If call flow is `accessToken` (Action) -> `issueAccessToken` -> `createAccessToken` -> `insert`, then you will have to add `implicit req` as parameter to declaration of `issueAccessToken` & `createAccessToken` so that `request` is propagated up to `implicit` scope when calling `insert`.

Comment: Thanks again for your update - could I rephrase it slightly to check I have understood.

If code execution is at a point after the controller Action, and the request object hasn't been passed down (via parameters or using implicit) then there is no way to get a reference to request.

Is that the correct understanding?

Comment: Right. As said, `implicit parameter` is by first a parameter. That's not an automagic global like in some other langages (e.g. earlier PHP version). It as to specified as expected input (parameter) in function declaration, or function body won't have access to. This 'unmagic' way help as compiler is checking things for you: making sure the calling context is valid according callee expectations.